# Displaying a variable length and height 2D array of squares on a web page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm developing a web application that displays a stack of shipping containers in a 2D array format. The width and height of the stack can vary so I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to produce a grid/table of squares that will represent the container stack reliably. The container locations will be pulled from a database.

[image: Stack Of Shipping Containers]

[image: Command Line representation of container indexes (0 indicates empty space)]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Posting your code helps us to find a solution for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you show the work you've done to try to accomplish this yourself and provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example we can help you a lot more. For more understanding, see why is ["please help" not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a variety of ways you can approach this. My example below uses the flexbox layout; you can use something like the CSS I included, and then all you have to do is generate one `<div class="stack">` for each stack of containers, and then one `<div class="cont">` within each stack for each container (if I understood your description correctly).

```css
.containers {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.containers .stack {
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.containers .cont {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="containers">
  <div class="stack">
    <div class="cont">2</div>
    <div class="cont">11</div>
    <div class="cont">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stack">
    <div class="cont">3</div>
    <div class="cont">5</div>
    <div class="cont">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stack">
    <div class="cont">8</div>
    <div class="cont">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stack">
    <div class="cont">4</div>
    <div class="cont">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stack">
    <div class="cont">6</div>
    <div class="cont">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question, this is what I was looking for. I'll take the feedback on board and will be more specific when answering further questions.